# Synchronizing Redis Read and Write Operations in Express.js to Avoid Data Overwrite

Tags: node.js, express, redis

I'm facing an issue in my application where I'm reading data from Redis and performing manipulations on it based on the read value. However, when I receive multiple requests with very minor time differences on the same route, I end up getting the same value from Redis for both operations. It seems like the first request hasn't completed its read and write operation fully before the second request starts.

I want to ensure that I always read and write data synchronously for all requests coming in for a specific Redis key to avoid data inconsistencies. How can I effectively synchronize read and write operations in Express.js with Redis to ensure that each request operates on the most up-to-date data?

```
const express = require('express');
const redis = require('redis');

const app = express();
const client = redis.createClient();

app.get('/data', (req, res) => {
 const key = req.query.key;

 // Read data from Redis
 client.get(key, (err, data) => {
     if (err) {
         res.status(500).send('Error reading data from Redis');
         return;
     }

     // Manipulate data
     // ...

     // Write manipulated data back to Redis
     client.set(key, manipulatedData, (err) => {
         if (err) {
             res.status(500).send('Error writing data to Redis');
             return;
         }

         res.send('Data successfully manipulated and updated in Redis');
     });
 });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
 console.log('Server is running on port 3000');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a single environment, use a lock around the redis key. [https://brunoscheufler.com/blog/2021-05-31-locking-and-synchronization-for-nodejs]

If you need to handle it from many clients, you could lock using redis. https://redis.io/docs/manual/patterns/distributed-locks/

https://github.com/mike-marcacci/node-redlock

Answer (score 0):

You could use [WATCH](https://redis.io/commands/watch/) and [MULTI](https://redis.io/commands/multi/) to do this. This isn't JavaScript code but the command sequence against Redis would be:

First, WATCH the key and GET the value:

```
redis.cloud:6379> WATCH foo
redis.cloud:6379> GET foo
```

Then, run your code that manipulates the value.

```bash
redis.cloud:6379> MULTI
redis.cloud:6379> SET foo value
redis.cloud:6379> EXEC
```

Then run a [transaction](https://redis.io/docs/interact/transactions/) to SET the updated value.

Normally you use MULTI to execute, well, multiple things. It does this atomically. Nothing else can run when it is happening.

However, with WATCH, it will watch the key and if anyone changed it between the call to WATCH and the call to EXEC, EXEC will throw an error. Then you can just retry or give up or whatever you'd like.

I do know that with Node Redis you'll want to use an isolated connection as MUTLI doesn't play nice with connection pooling if you're doing a WATCH.

Details for the JavaScript bits are in the [Node Redis README](https://github.com/redis/node-redis?tab=readme-ov-file#transactions-multiexec).